# Giving Edit access to the opportunity owner's Reporting Executive

Tags: opportunity, field-level-security

I am new to Salesforce.I have created a custom field on opportunity.Requirement is:This field should be visible to all users under a particular profile but should be ediatable only by the opportunity's owner's reporting executive.This reporting executive field is on opportunity owner user detail page.

Can someone help me how to fulfill this requirement.This is high priority task for me.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can take this approach:

1. Create a permission set called `Reporting Executive Permission Set` where you assign 'Edit' permission to Report Executive User field.
2. During opportunity create or update operation, write a trigger to assign permission set to the `Reporting Executive User` taking from Opportunity record.

Insert script to add permission set is as follows:

```
List<PermissionSet> psList = [select id, name from permissionset where name = 'Reporting Executive Permission Set'];

//assign permission set to user
if(psList.size()>0){
PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = userId, PermissionSetId = psList[0].Id);
insert psa;
}
```

`userId` is the `Reporting Executive User Id` of Opportunity

3. If there is any update on `Reporting Executive User` field, you need to remove previous `PermissionSetAssignment` record of the old user and create new `PermissionSetAssignment` record for updated user.